# How does one get rid of the CSS errors regarding dashicons.eot

Tags: wordpress, 4.7, css

Or is this a Microsoft Edge only problem?

[image: Console Errors]

Comment: Are you 100% that the `dashicons.eot` reference is coming from CiviCRM? I don't see it in my CiviCRM codebase.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's generic question about html and css, should go to SO

Answer (score 1):

The page you loaded seems to be about widgets and not related to civicrm